# Curious where Financial Data APIs get data

Tags: programming

First time posting on this stack exchange, but I was using Polygon to get some Market Data recently, and I was curious about one thing.

Where do they get their data from? Might be a dumb question, but what's stopping "normal" investors from making their own API? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need a connection to the data providers (e.g. exchanges). You can see details on [Poligon's website](https://polygon.io/stocks?gclid=Cj0KCQjwsdiTBhD5ARIsAIpW8CI1oTHfE4dr_86WKDwpU0kqmT3ePmfAGwDOlY6XGOQi38ImQrryy_gaAm9aEALw_wcB).

[image]

A counter question may be, what prevents you from building your own [numpy](https://numpy.org/) or [R charting library](https://mode.com/blog/r-data-visualization-packages/)? Or a bit broader, bake your own bread, build your own  car?

Usually the answer will be that someone already spent a lot of time and resources on building something that just works well, and trying to replicate this will just take unnecessary time.

Comment: If you would like to hook up to the NYSE directly, the prices are not cheap https://www.nyse.com/publicdocs/nyse/data/NYSE_Market_Data_Fee_Schedule.pdf and that's just 1 data source. There will usually be 1 or 2 intermediaries between that feed and an ordinary user, providing data checking/reformatting, storage, backup, and other necessary functions.